# Is there a pattern name for allowing users to add fields?

Tags: design-patterns, terminology, input-fields, input

[image: Example one.]

---

[image: Example two.]

---

[image: Example three.]

---

When a user is allowed to add/remove additional fields (or field groups) within a form, what is this interface paradigm called?

EDIT: in the example screenshots, each "row" of field(s) can be added/removed by the user, building up a list of "things".

There's a separate question about this type of input paradigm ([Allowing the user to add input fields](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/92875/allowing-the-user-to-add-input-fields)). It's asking about design/workflow, but not the name of the pattern. However, all/most of the screen examples on that question are relevant examples for my question

Comment: why? what on earth is the use case?

Comment: @colmcq I've edited my question to add a little more information. Also have a look at the screen examples in this comment on another thread https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/92892/120623 

I'm not asking if one "should" use this paradigm. I'm simply asking if it has a common name

Comment: are you really just allowing the user to 'add object'? That's what it feels like.

Comment: @colmcq I don't see why you're having such an issue with his question.

Comment: @big_chair As I see it: OP is asking the name of the pattern for when you add an object to a table of objects. That's how I see this.

Comment: I suppose it's Dynamically addable (and removable) rows/fields.

Comment: Redux Forms for React calls them "FieldArray(s)" https://redux-form.com/7.0.2/examples/fieldarrays/ which is great from a developer perspective, but not sure if this is palatable from a UI design pattern naming perspective

Answer (score 1):

I think the closest that you'll come to an exact name for this is either

**Dynamic or Expandable Forms**

---

Found these references for that:

[Another pattern for Dynamic/Expanding forms?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/105724/another-pattern-for-dynamic-expanding-forms)

[dynamic form design](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/22004/dynamic-form-design)

[UI Patterns: expandable input](http://ui-patterns.com/patterns/expandable-input) (this one is only weakly connected to our case here but it still conveys a similar thought)

Comment: I see the first two as good examples; the last one....not sure at all

Comment: Thanks for the input! (see what I did there?) As names/labels alone, I think these all feel very general in a not entirely wrong kind of way. I was hoping for something a little more specific/descriptive, but I think this is headed in the right direction.